# Scala - while loop to for-comprehension

Tags: scala

Is it possible to achieve the same functionality as

```
def filler(input: Array[Float], output: Array[Float]): Unit = {
    var maxValue:Float = 0
    var idx:Int = 1

    output(0)= input(0)
    while(idx < input.length) {
        output(idx) = max(input(idx)/idx,maxValue)
        maxValue = output(idx)
        idx = idx + 1
    }
}
```

with the help of for comprehension, or to rewrite it in any other "functional" way?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: I don't believe you. Prove it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def filler(input: Array[Float]): Array[Float] = {
  input.zipWithIndex.scanLeft(0.0f) {
    case (maxValue, (x, i)) => max(x/Math.max(1, i), maxValue)
  }.tail
}
```

Comment: I think `zipWithIndex` should be replaced by `zip(Stream from 1)`. That should buy you something.

Comment: Not sure that would simplify it much. `Math.max(1, i)` would need to be replaced by, for instance `if(i > 1) i - 1 else i` which is pretty comparable.